# Roll over value from previous row when row is null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have problem in rolling over value from previous row when value is null. I currently have a dataset

```
+------+---------+
month.   average
+------+---------+
01/2018    null
02/2018    null
03/2018    4
04/2018    10
05/2018    null
06/2018    20
07/2018    null
```

My desired output should look similar to this. I'm trying to roll over previous value where average is null

```
+------+---------+
month.   average
+------+---------+
01/2018    0
02/2018    0
03/2018    4
04/2018    10
05/2018    10
06/2018    20
07/2018    20
```

I tried the lag function but the null keeps appearing.

my current query looks similar to this:

```
with cte as(
select to_char(created_at,'MM') || to char(created_at,'YYYY') as month
,AVG(CASE WHEN status ='ready' THEN col ELSE null END) as average
from table
group by month
)
select 
month
,lag(average) over (order by month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as average
from cte
```

Comment: 1) Only tag the actual RDBMS you are using. 2) Show us what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Please share the query with Lag()

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur.  with cute as(select to_char(created_at,'YYYY') || to char(created_at,'MM') as month,AVG(CASE WHEN status =ready THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as average from table group by

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur the query has been added to the post

Comment: You mentioned you tried with `lag` function, but I don't see it in you query

Comment: @partlov I updated the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be `lag(ignore nulls)`, but Postgres does not support that.

If you just have one `NULL` in a row, then `lag()` is sufficient (as another answer suggests).  But that is not very generalizable.

If the values are known to be increasing a cumulative max is probably the most efficient:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(max(average) over (order by month), 0) as imputed_average
from t;
```

This works with multiple `NULL`s in a row.  If the data doesn't have that increasing property, then another alternative is two levels of window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(max(average) over (partition by non_null_month), 0) as imputed_average
from (select t.*,
             max(month) filter (where average is not null) over (order by month) as non_null_month
      from t
     ) t;
```

There is another method using arrays.  It doesn't require subqueries, but it might not scale well:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce((array_remove(array_agg(average) over (order by month), null))[cardinality(array_remove(array_agg(average) over (order by month), null))], 0) as imputed_average
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6c1707dd15cd88ee33d09a271809657a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: max(average) doesn't work if average is more than the last  non null value for that row, right?

Comment: @eshirvana . . . That is correct.  I think the answer explains that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff trying this syntax select t.*,
       coalesce(max(average) over (partition by non_null_month), 0) as imputed_average
from (select t.*,
             max(month) filter (where average is not null) over (order by month) as non_null_month
      from t
     ) t;..I got a syntax error

Comment: @Mandibajr . . . I fixed the third query and added a db<>fiddle.  There was some wishful programming in my original answer.

Comment: select t.*,
       coalesce((array_remove(array_agg(average) over (order by month), null))[cardinality(array_remove(array_agg(average) over (order by month), null))], 0) as imputed_average
from t; this works but the other option returns error still

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you please give a more elaborate explanation on the two option please for reusability. thanks

Comment: @Mandibajr . . . All three are in the db<>fiddle with working examples.

Answer (score -1):

use coalesce

```
select 
  month,
  COALESCE(average,
           lag(average) over (order by month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),
           0) as average
from cte
```

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto, the point was to show how to use coalesce with lag -- but I didn't check if the lag statement made sense....

Comment: that doesn't work if there are multiple null values in between , also LAG() has default value parameter , no need for COALESCE

Comment: @eshirvana -- I was going by his example he wanted there to be a 0 if multiple nulls